# type not inferred correclty in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, slick

I am using `slick`'s `for expression`, and seeing some strangeness in terms of intellij's inferred type. Here are the unexpected result:

[image]

[image]

Why in the second case, it is not `Query[Int, Int]` but instead becomes `Query[Nothing, Nothing]`. I seem to lose some type information.

Comment: you could report this bug to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/. They usually fix such issues pretty quickly.

Comment: that's the tuple syntax.

Answer (score 1):

What's to say? IDEA has it's own parser and typer and it is not that hard to confuse it. If you care about fidelity between your IDE and the Scala compiler, the Scala IDE (which runs in Eclipse) would be better for you.

Personally, I dislike Eclipse more than I do the vagaries of the IDEA Scala plug-in.

Comment: just want to add, that using type libraries like shapeless or scalaz, it is a very often situation that even lines are marked (or underlined) with red.

Comment: Indeed, Shapeless and ScalaZ are full of code that IDEA can't follow. … [editorializing] One might consider IDEA's ability to folow the types in any given code base as a proxy for a human's ability to do so…